# Probability of one side of card being red given other side is red?

Tags: probability

*A box contains 6 cards. 3 are black on both sides, 1 is black on one side and red on the other, and the last 2 are red on both sides.
You pick a card out of the box uniformly at random and look at a side also randomly. Given that the side you see is red, what is the probability that the other side is red?*

I'm getting the wrong answer and can't figure out what's wrong with my reasoning.

I'm thinking once you see a red side, it can be one of three cards; the 2 fully red ones or the one with a red side and a black side.
So at this point, 2 out of the 3 cards you could be holding will be red on the other side.
Hence your chance is $\frac{2}{3}$

The correct answer (presumably) is

> $\frac{4}{5}$ because you have to consider each side as a separate object

and I don't understand the logic behind that

Comment: If you label the sides of the cards, say F and B (front and back), that might help you to see the various combinations.

Comment: Probability of getting a card with at least one red side in the bunch: $\frac{1}{2}$. You now see that the side of the card you have is red, so the remaining possibilities for the other side are black, red, red, red, red because there is 1 black/red card and 2 red/red cards. Why is there not a fifth red in the mix? Shouldn't you have 2 x red/red + red = 5 red sides? This is due to the fact that you have to remove the color of the side you looked at, which in this case, was red. So the probability that the other side being red is: [red, red, red, red] / [red, red, red, red, black] = $4/5$.

Answer (score 3):

With a prob of 1/2 you pull a black card, which does not interest us. With 1/3 you pull a red card. With 1/6 you pull a mixed one, where with prob 1/2 you have the red face, so a prob of $1/6\cdot 1/2 = 1/12$. Thus we have a total probability for red of
$$ 1/3 + 1/12 = 5/12 $$

Now, if we face a red side we are either in the case of a red card with 1/3 or in the case with a mixed card with a prob of 1/6. Thus we have a chance of

P(side is red $\cap$ card is red) = P(card is red | side is red)·P(side is red)

so

P(card is red | side is red) = P(side is red $\cap$ card is red) / P(side is red) = 1/3 / (5/12) = 4/5

Your reasoning is wrong because: While the probability for a red card (of course always facing the red side) is simply $1/3$, the probability for a mixed card *facing the red side* is not 1/6 but 1/12.

So it is much less probable that you encounter the mixed card if the facing side is red, as half of the time the facing side will be black.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Bayes's Theorem.  You are equally likely to have seen any of $5$ red sides.  For $4$ of those selections, the card's other side also will be red.  Therefore, the requested probability is $0.8$.

The problem with your analysis is that once you know that you're looking at a red side, you are no longer equally likely to have selected any of the possible cards. You can make that a little more intuitive.  Suppose the cards had $1,000,000$ "sides" each.  For two of the cards, all of the sides are red, but for one of the cards, only one of the million sides is red.  Do you still think that, if you see a red side, each of the three possible cards with at least one red side is equally likely?

Answer (score 1):

Saying you pick one of the sides with equal probability is the fastest way to solve this.

Here is the slow way:

- you originally pick a black/black card with probability $\frac36=\frac12$

  - the probability you pick a black/black card and see a black side has probability $\frac12 \times \frac22=\frac1{2}$
- you originally pick a red/black card with probability $\frac16$

  - the probability you pick a red/black card and see a black side has probability $\frac16 \times \frac12=\frac1{12}$
  - the probability you pick a red/black card and see a red side has probability $\frac16 \times \frac12=\frac1{12}$
- you originally pick a red/red card with probability $\frac26=\frac13$

  - the probability you pick a red/red card and see a red side has probability $\frac13 \times \frac22=\frac1{3}$

So the probability you see a red side is $\frac1{12}+\frac13= \frac5{12}$ while the probability you pick a red/red card and see a red side has probability $\frac1{3}$

meaning the conditional probability both sides are red given you see a red side is $\frac{1/3}{5/12}=\frac45$

Answer (score 0):

By picking a card uniformly and then a side uniformly, you have picked one of the 12 card sides uniformly. The colors cannot change the fact that this two-step picking process yields equal probability of choosing any of the 12 card sides. If the side you picked is red, you know that you picked one of the 5 red sides with equal probability (1/5). For one of the red sides, the other side is black. For the other four of the red sides, the other side is also red. So with probability 4/5, the other side is red, and with probability 1/5, the other side is black.